# Will video drivers after upgrade to 13.04 still work?

Tags: drivers, upgrade, ati, radeon

The biggest fear I have if I upgrade to 13.04 is that the video driver I use will no longer work on the new version.

I'm currently using a AMD Radeon and the driver is here http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English

But I don't want to upgrade and find that the driver doesn't work. If I don't have a 3D driver the computer will be useless.

Can anyone confirm that these drivers will work with 13.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of the driver was released yesterday, it should work perfectly after the upgrade. just make sure you have the latest version.